# Tableview last row is cut off under tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having a Tabbarcontroller and in the first tabview I'm having a tableviewcontroller. Now the last row is half visible the rest is underneath the tabbarcontroller.

I've unchecked extend edges in the interface builder of my tabbar controller but nothing changes.

I also tried this in my tableview controller:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

But still the last row is half underneath the tabbar.

Someone an idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this inside viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame), 0.0f); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Find it odd that when You set it in the interface builder it doesn't work and in code it does.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but the swift solution to this would be to just add the line:

`self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None`

to your ViewController's `ViewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

I had this problem and was searching for answers for hours. Going into storyboard and unchecking "Under Bottom Bars" didn't work. I came across this answer but kept getting a nil when trying to access the height of the tabBar like Sanjay did. I hardcoded the tabBar height instead and it was all gravy.

In viewDidLoad add the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tabBarHeight = CGFloat(49)
    edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.all
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: tabBarHeight, right: 0.0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the TabBar being translucent by default in IB, if you don't need this effect you can change it with code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  tabBarController?.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

Or in IB by selecting your tabBar and uncheck the Translucent box.